# Chrome Browser not loading the web page using selenium

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome, selenium, testing, browser-automation

I am using selenium to automate a web page using chrome browser , but the chrome browser is not launching and it is showing "data:;" in the address bar without loading any page .

Selenium : selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2 and also tried with 2.53

Chrome Driver :  2.23 (http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.23/)

Eclipse : Kepler

Chrome Browser : Version 53.0.2785.89 m (64-bit)

Following is the code i am using

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Vinod\\Java\\Others\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Testing");
```

Below is the output :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klVO4.jpg)

Appreciate your help in this - Thanks.

Comment: As I see the page is still loading, you should add a wait and see what happens. data:; is a default data.

Comment: Its getting session timeout

Comment: Can you try with downgrading Google Chrome, you are using latest.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know you are going absolutely fine. You just need to be bit patient.

The page which you get with data:, is what we expect initially from selenium. You google page will launch  after that.